# Angular DateTime Format

Tags: json, angular, datetime, angular6, angular7

I have this json array with datetime strings. and I am populating this data in the table.

```
[{"id":8,"startdate":"2018-02-01T00:00:00","enddate":"2018-02-28T23:59:59.9999999","created":"2018-02-15T12:58:43.3417189","filename":"data022018"},{"id":9,"startdate":"2019-03-01T00:00:00","enddate":"2019-03-31T23:59:59.9999999","created":"2019-03-15T12:59:45.1079351","filename":"data032019"},{"id":10,"startdate":"2019-04-01T00:00:00","enddate":"2019-04-30T23:59:59.9999999","created":"2019-04-08T12:58:43.3417189","filename":"data042019"}]
```

this is html code in my table

```
<td>{{ archive.startdate | date: 'short' }} - {{ archive.enddate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
```

the result is

```
2/1/18, 12:00 AM - 01/03/2018 (just want to show i format with different methods)
1/4/2018 - 1/5/2018
```

what i really want to achieve is the last date to be on the last day of the month instead of starting from first day of following month.

```
1/02/2018 - 28/02/2018
```

What did i do wrong? I want to take enddate day,month and year.

Answers thanks to @Wandrille

```
//model
export interface Archive {
    id?: string | number;
    startdate: string | Date; <-- use as string or date object
    enddate: string | Date;
    created: string | Date;
    filename: string;
}

 // component
 this.db.getFiles(
  this.currentPage,
  this.pageSize
  ).subscribe(result => {
    this.totalArchives = result.totalitems;
    this.archives = result.items.map(myitem => ({
      ...myitem,
      startdate: new Date(myitem.startdate), <-- after init as new date, date pipe work as expected
      enddate: new Date(myitem.enddate) <-- date pipe works
    }));
    if(this.totalArchives === '0' || this.totalArchives === 0) {
      this.toastr.info('No Files Yet', 'Waiting for files to generate');
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your date string into *Date*. and then, it will works (and also be cleaner)

```
this.archive = this.archive.map(item => (
   {
    ...item,
    startdate : new Date(item.startdate),
    endDate : new Date(item.endDate)
   }
))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for value after `:`

Try like this

```
{{ startdate.split(":")[0]| date: 'short'}} 
 <br>
{{ enddate.split(":")[0]| date: 'short'}}
```

See detail [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6jdne)